# Get hidden folders in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I am making a browser in my application where I want to get all the folders and subfolders even if they are hidden. The code which I used is the following:

```
    try {
        FileConnection fileConnection = (FileConnection)Connector.open(path);
        if (fileConnection.isDirectory()) {
            Enumeration directoryEnumerator = fileConnection.list();
            Vector contentVector = new Vector();
            while(directoryEnumerator.hasMoreElements()) {
                contentVector.addElement(directoryEnumerator.nextElement());
            }
            fileConnection.close();
        }
     } catch (Exception ex) { }
```

But using the FileConnection and the Connector, I didn't get the hidden files and directories ... How to get them? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of JDE are you using?

You should be able to do this:

```
 Enumeration directoryEnumerator = fileConnection.list("*", true);
```

You can read more in the [Blackberry Javadoc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#list%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FileConnection.list(filter, includeHidden)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#list%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) method:

```
Enumeration directoryEnumerator = fileConnection.list("*", true);
```